# How can I put something in the prompt and get the output inside of a node program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the World Time API in my program. However, to use that I need to write "curl http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/:area/:location[/:region]" in the prompt and receive a output. How can I write and get the output?

I tried do something with console.log but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fetch](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Amsterdam')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json(); // converts response to json
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // do something with data here
     console.log(data)
  });
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Now, can u tell me how can I manipulate this json? I just need one line.

Comment: Returned `data` variable is an javascript object, so if you want to acces only one prop, you can do it by typing `data.prop`. In this case, if you want to access timezone prop for example, just type `data.timezone`.
Also I really encourage you to read more about the [javascript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your API without writing an actual program that calls it, 
[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is the best app to use. Watch quick tutorials on youtube on how to use it. Its not that complicated.